# Filezilla Issue. Plese help

Tags: 14.04, filezilla

I'm able to upload files by FileZilla, but when I try to download files from the same sites I receive:

Error: Failed to open "/file" for writing
Error: File transfer failed

However, I'm able to use other ftp clients to upload and download to the same ftp sites. I can also successfully download the files on filezilla by using the "view/edit" option instead of the download option.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to download to different folders ?, it seems that it don't have write permission to folder where you tried to download file and you can view/edit because it is downloaded to /tmp directory...(I cant test my theory because I don't have access to any ftp at the moment)

Comment: Thanks Martinko. I have tried different folders. I have changed folder permission to 777 and try to download but not working.

Comment: @Sisyphus Excerpt Could you post the full path that you tried to write?